# Best way to create entity objects with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns

I'm just getting started with TypeScript and wanted to know if this is the best approach on initializing entity objects with data coming from an API.

How I did it before with `JavaScript`:

```
class Entity {
  constructor(apiResponseData = {}) {
    this.id = apiResponseData.id
    this.set = apiResponseData.set
    ...
  }

  toObject() {
    return { id: this.id, ... }
  }
}
```

For my approach with `TypeScript`:

```
interface EntityData {
  id: string
  set: string,
  ...
}

class Entity {
  id: string
  set: string
  
  constructor(apiResponseData: EntityData) {
    this.id = apiResponseData.id
    this.set = apiResponseData.set
    ...
  }

  toObject() {
    return { id: this.id, ... }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this in `TypeScript`? It duplicates a lot of code due to declaring types multiple times and so it gets big the more properties I need to define.

An alternate way I thought of could be:

```
interface EntityData {
  id: string
  set: string,
  ...
}

interface Entity extends EntityData {
  toObject: () => EntityData
}

const buildEntity = (apiResponseData: EntityData) => {
  return {
    id: apiResponseData.id,
    set: apiResponseData.set,
    ...
    toObject: () => ({ id: apiResponseData.id, ... }) // imagine if method does some other operations to the data
  }
}
```

My only concern for this approach is if member data is changed (ex. `id=1` => `id=2` after entity is built), then `toObject()` will be incorrect.

Any ideas or other approaches?

Comment: "*My only concern for this approach is if member data is changed, then toObject() will be incorrect.*" - just write `return { …, toObject() { return {id: this.id,…}; } };` then

Comment: Do you intend `class Entity implements EntityData`?

Comment: @Bergi, ahh you're right, I was using arrow function which made `this` not work. And for Entity I will be implementing `EntityData`. I went with Tomas' approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the best way is to do it in TypeScript but there are some things you can do simpler.

```
interface EntityData {
    id: string;
    set: string,
}

// don't declare two properties,
// just create an interface
interface Entity extends EntityData {}

class Entity {
    // destruct data
    constructor({id, set}: EntityData) {
        this.id = id;
        this.set = set;
    }

    toObject(): EntityData {
        // destruct all own properties
        // (not methods in prototype)
        return {...this};
    }
}
```

I used destructing which is ECMAScript 6 standard. If you don't know it, see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for more info.

Comment: oh cool, I didn't realize that having the same name for an interface and class will be merged into one, thanks!

Comment: Yes, TypeScript is awesome. And now, please, click the checkmark in this block for accepting the answer. Thank you.